# Aumentar e diminuir a quantidade do elemento seleciondo através da classe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Então na seguinte parte do meu código eu tenha uma função para aumentar a quantidade ou diminuir de cada produto da loja(Vou deixar uma foto para explicar melhor), quando eu aperto no botão "+" ele aumenta a quantidade e no "-" diminui, porém ele só aumenta no primeiro elemento que tem a classe que eu selecionei mesmo eu tentando aumentar a quantidade do ultimo produto que aparece, por exemplo, se eu aumentar a quantidade do produto "chocolate blend gotas" ele aumenta a quantidade apenas do primeiro produto "cobertura ao leite". Acho que pelo fato de eu usar o querySelector ele pega o primeiro elemento selecionado, contudo quero que ele selecione o elemento Atual ao qual eu clico.

Código da quantidade:

```
<div>
    <div class="produto_qnt_princ" data-app="product.quantity">     
      <input class="qnt_menor_maior" type="button" id="plus" value='-' onclick="process_geral(-1)" />
      <input class="quanti qnt_menor_maior" name="quanti" class="text" size="1" type="text" value="1" maxlength="5" />
      <input class="qnt_menor_maior" type="button" id="minus" value='+' onclick="process_geral(1)" /> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Código da função que é chamada:

```
function process_geral(quant){
    var classValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('.quanti').value);
    classValue+=quant;
    //console.log(classValue); 
    if(classValue < 1){
        document.querySelector("input.quanti").value = 1;
    }else{ 
        document.querySelector("input.quanti").value = classValue;    
    }
}
```

Foto a qual me referi:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução para a minha resposta foi a seguinte: Eu uso em meu sistema um mecanismo de template voltada para PHP (Twig) e com ele eu consigo retornar o valor do id de cada produto (atraves do {{product.id}} ), então a minha solução foi passar como parametro da função quando ele é clicada a quantidade a ser incrementada ou decrementada e o id do produto. Ai na minha função eu faço uma validação para comparar se o valor do id do produto selecionado é o mesmo id do produto que foi passado como parametro, ai caso seja o mesmo valor eu guardo esse elemento e depois passo o valor da quantidade que ele deve ter.

```
<div data-product="{{ product.id }}">
    <div class="produto_qnt_princ" data-product="{{ product.id }}" data-app="product.quantity">      
      <input class="qnt_menor_maior" type="button" id="plus" value='-' onclick="process_geral(-1,'{{ product.id }}')" />
      <input class="quanti qnt_menor_maior" name="quanti" class="text" size="1" type="text" value="1" maxlength="5" />
      <input class="qnt_menor_maior" type="button" id="minus" value='+' onclick="process_geral(1,'{{ product.id }}')" />
      <p> {{ product.id }} </p>  
    </div>    
</div>
```

```
function process_geral(quant, indice){ 
    const todosProdutos = document.getElementsByClassName('produto_qnt_princ');
    
    // Para filtrar você pode fazer assim:
    /*const produtoFiltrado = todosProdutos.filter(e => e.dataset.indice === indice);
    ou pode usar o for implementado abaixo*/
    var i,len;
    var produtoFiltrado; 

        for (i = 0,len=todosProdutos.length;i<len; i++) {
            //console.log(todosProdutos[i].getAttribute('data-product'));
            if (todosProdutos[i].getAttribute('data-product') === indice) {
                //console.log(todosProdutos[i].getAttribute('data-product'));
                produtoFiltrado = todosProdutos[i];
            }
        }
    
    var classValue = parseInt(produtoFiltrado.querySelector('input.quanti').value);
    classValue+=quant; 

    if(classValue < 1){
        produtoFiltrado.querySelector("input.quanti").value = 1;
    }else{  
        produtoFiltrado.querySelector("input.quanti").value = classValue;     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```html
<script>
function process_geral(quant, element){
    var classValue = parseInt(element.parentElement.querySelector('.quanti').value);
    classValue+=quant;
    //console.log(classValue); 
    if(classValue < 1){
        element.parentElement.querySelector("input.quanti").value = 1;
    }else{ 
        element.parentElement.querySelector("input.quanti").value = classValue;    
    }
}  
</script>
<div>
    <div class="produto_qnt_princ" data-app="product.quantity">     
      <input class="qnt_menor_maior" type="button" id="plus" value='-' onclick="process_geral(-1, this)" />
      <input class="quanti qnt_menor_maior" name="quanti" class="text" size="1" type="text" value="1" maxlength="5" />
      <input class="qnt_menor_maior" type="button" id="minus" value='+' onclick="process_geral(1, this)" /> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

O que foi feito é basicamente passar a referência do objeto no evento e usar o elemento pai dele para encontrar o input com a quantidade.

Existem outras formas mais elegantes de fazer isso, mas acredito que deva funcionar

Comment: então está aparecendo a seguinte informação no console: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined"

Comment: Em qual linha do código?

Comment: nessa parte "var classValue = parseInt(element.parentElement.querySelector('.quanti').value);"